# Issues with running SQL data dump scripts - mysql: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to run a couple SQL scripts to import schemas in MySQL Workbench 8.0 but I'm running into problems with getting them to execute. When I execute them the following errors popup:

> Preparing...
> Importing ks-data.sql...
>
> Finished executing script
>
> mysql: [ERROR] Failed to open required defaults file: c:\users\username
>
> mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

[image: Error Window]

I've tried to uninstall/reinstall MySQL Workbench but it didn't help.
Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You say you are running a DUMP but the error say you are running an IMPORT. Which is it?

Comment: It's a SQL script meant to import a schema into MySQL, sorry for the misunderstanding, I'll edit that!

Comment: So you are IMPORTING a previously generated DUMP(Export) So how was the export/dump run? Was it on the same version of MySQL?

Comment: Did you use WorkBench or phpMyAdmin or mysqldump or something else?

Comment: I used Workbench for this. I ran the SQL file through File > Run SQL Script.
I ran 2 scripts, one was from Server 8.0 and another was Server 5.7

Comment: And what version are you trying to load then too

Comment: MySQL Server/Workbench 8.0

Comment: And MySQL Version?

Comment: MySQL is 8.0 as well

Comment: If it's any help, I can import the SQL files and create the schemas by opening them up in Workbench and then manually running them through Workbench but whenever I try to run them through File > Run SQL Script, I get the above error message.

Opening and running them manually is not practical always and I'd want to try to get to the bottom of this issue

Comment: How would I confirm/check that I do have the proper permissions?

Comment: @hatirlatici Postgress? I am pretty sure MySQL Workbench does not work with Postgress

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The reason was the path of %AppData% contained non-utf8 characters like Chinese characters.

Windows uses GBK as the default charset, and if any character sees in the path, you will receive this error.

I'm not sure if Windows with other language has this problem. Hope this answer will help you.